# How to install a git package's dependencies

Tags: git, npm, npm-install

I have a project with a `package.json` file like so:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "my-package": "git+https://shoreline:password@bitbucket.org/shorelineltd/my-package.git"
  }
}
```

The "my-package" `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress --colors",
    "watch": "webpack --progress --colors --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --env.dev --open --watch --progress --colors"
  },
  "author": "shoreline@anonymised-domain.com",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/shorelineltd/my-package#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.7",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.4.7",
    "angular-schema-form": "0.8.13",
    "angular-schema-form-bootstrap": "0.2.0",
    "angular-schema-form-dynamic-select": "0.13.1",
    "angular-toastr": "2.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7"
  }
}
```

The `npm` version is 4.2.0.

When I run `npm install` my package source code downloads successfully.

How do I make my `npm install` include the dependencies given within "my-package"?

Should I be including a bundle within "my-package"?

Comment: What does your my-package's `package.json` look like? What version of npm do you use? The fact that it's acquired via git is not relevant (barring an undiscovered bug).

Comment: As long as you have a `package.json` in the root, that should happen automatically.

Comment: I second with @SLaks, if package.json is present in node_modules/my-package, it should happen automatically.

Comment: Included the "my-package" `package.json` and NPM version in the OP.